# HTTP Class that extends asyncore.dispatcher

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

Is there "standard" or well known class that do HTTP Client using asyncore.dispatcher ?

I can do one, but I prefer not to invent the wheel again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, at least not anything you'd want to use.

Most people believe that `asyncore` is somewhat useful as "sample code" on how to write a `select`-based event loop, but not useful as a framework for real-life projects beyond trivial complexity.

There have been a few projects in the past to build serious things on top of `asyncore`, including at least one web *server*, but I don't know of a web *client*. That doesn't mean that no such thing exists… but I wouldn't expect it to be well-maintained or heavily-used.

Instead of building higher-level frameworks on top of `asyncore`, people have mostly focused on building new frameworks from scratch. The most popular are probably [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com) (which has a vaguely similar architecture to `asyncore`, but much more powerful and flexible) and [`gevent`](http://gevent.org) (which is very different—it lets you write code in the synchronous/multithreaded style and it magically runs via greenlets in a single thread around an event loop).

Meanwhile, Guido and friends are designing a new, modern async library (see [PEP 3146](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/) and [`tulip`](http://code.google.com/p/tulip/) for details) that will probably appear in 3.4, and may deprecate `asyncore`.

So, your choices are:

- Build it yourself out of `httplib` and `asyncore`.
- Search for an old, partially-finished implementation and finish it.
- Use `twisted`, `gevent`, `tulip`, etc.
- Use a different high-level abstraction like [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net) (or any of the other libraries that wrap `libcurl` and its `curl_multi` API) or [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (which asynchronizes the very high-level `requests` HTTP client library using `gevent`).

Of course it's also worth considering whether you really need a single-threaded event loop. Most client-side apps don't need to handle more than a dozen or so connections, and a thread per socket can easily handle that on any platform. (Of course Python threads suck if you have any CPU-bound code, but single-threaded event-loop-based code sucks even *worse* for that, so I'll assume that isn't a problem.)

---

First, a couple general comments on your comments:

I'm not sure what you mean by "performance". Normally, with networking apps, you worry about *scalability*: How many simultaneous connections can you handle, how many new connections you can make per second, how much throughput you can sustain, etc. *Performance*—usually measured in terms of how much CPU/power-draw/heat-dissipation you're using during a steady-state workflow—usually only comes into it once you've got all the scalability you need, and even then only if you're planning on running dozens of rooms stacked with boxes running your server.

At any rate, I have no idea what you're testing, but *all* of these options demonstrably outpace `asyncore` on Linux and Mac OS X/*BSD, and completely blow it away on Windows, under any reasonable test anyone's ever done. They'll use IOCP, `epoll`, or `kqueue` instead of just `poll`. Some of them also put the central code in C. They're all being extensively tested and tuned under heavy real-world usage, while `asyncore` hasn't had any improvements since `poll` support was added more than a decade ago. (And that's not because `asyncore` is already good enough, but because it's not good enough to be worth improving.)

But for client-side apps, neither scalability nor performance is usually an issue. Just doing parallel downloads from a couple dozen sites is usually more than enough to saturate your FTTH/cable/DSL/etc. bandwidth, and beyond that, what more do you want?

So, the reason I suggested these alternatives was not for performance, or scalability, but for simplicity and completeness. Twisted's HTTP client or `grequests` means you only need to write 5 lines of code, and you have something that works, and all the hard parts are already thought through and heavily tested. Even building it yourself, it takes a whole lot less work (and offers a whole lot less opportunity for bugs) to run `httplib`/`urllib2`/whatever on top of `gevents` than to tear it apart and rebuild it around `asyncore` instead of blocking sockets.

> twisted - i am beginner, and dont have that much time to invest, at least for the moment.

While `twisted` is obviously a huge project, you don't have to learn *all* of it, and it should be much easier to use for a beginner than `asyncore`. Look at the HTTP client example  in the link I gave earlier. Compare that to how much code it would take to do the same thing with `httplib` and `asyncore`.

> gevent - performance is similar to asyncore, but server load is way to high.

If server load is way too high, that can only mean your client is running way too fast… And that's a good problem to have; you can always throttle back a too-fast client, but you generally can't do much with a too-slow client except rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: twisted - i am beginner, and dont have that much time to invest, at least for the moment.

gevent - performance is similar to asyncore, but server load is way to high.

pycurl with curl-muliti - performance is much slower than asyncore, tried implementations on python, php and C

grequests - nice library, but still not good performance

Comment: Since that's a lot of comments/questions, let me edit the answer to address them.

Comment: Thanks. How I can slow down gevent? using time.sleep() ?

Comment: First, you never ever want to use `time.sleep` in an event-loop-based app, because it puts your whole event loop to sleep. You stop reading data off the network (or responding to clicks, etc.). `gevent` _can_ monkeypatch `time.sleep` to call `gevent.sleep` instead, which just puts the current task to sleep, but why not just call `gevent.sleep` directly?

Comment: Second, usually you don't want sleep at all. If you're overburdening the server, it's probably because you're doing too many requests in parallel. Just don't do that. If you want to download 1000 files, instead of spawning 1000 simultaneous downloads, use a pool of 8 greenlets that all service a queue of 1000 URLs.

Comment: thanks for gevent.sleep()
using asyncore, I am able to do more parallel downloads and in same time load average is much lower than with gevent - this is at least what my test show.